# Do I have to know the basic spell version before I can select the mythic one?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, mythic-adventures

I need some help on how to learn and load mythic spells. The two relevant sources are:

> [Mythic Spell Lore](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/mythic-spell-lore-mythic) Benefit: You can learn a number of mythic
>   spells equal to your tier and can expend mythic power when casting
>   them to enhance the results.
>
> [Casting Mythic Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic): If you know the mythic version of a spell,
>   any time you cast the spell, you may expend one use of mythic power to
>   convert the spell into its mythic version as you cast it.

That says that on a Wizard 7/Mythic Tier 2. So I know two mythic spells (Dimension Door, Haste) and I have learned three Level 4 Spells (Acid Pit, Ghost Wolf, Solid Fog).

**My question is now:** To cast Dimension Door (Mythic) do I have to learn Dimension Door first, so I can *enhance the result*? In the case above I would not be able to cast Dimension Door or do I get the spell Dimension Door in addition to the three Level 4 spells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

The answer is right before the text you quoted:

> These spells aren't separate spells you gain as a spell known from your spellcasting class, but rather mythically charged versions of spells you already know.

It is also defined on the text of both [Mythic Spellcasting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes#TOC-Mythic-Spellcasting-Ex-) and [Mythic Spell Lore](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/mythic-spell-lore-mythic) abilities:

> To select a mythic spell, you must be able to cast the non-mythic version or have it on your list of spells known.